# Kinetic JS: Fading in a fill image when applying it to a polygon shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm having a play around with Kinetic JS at the moment, with the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8rtJ/4/

```
var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    width: 106,
    height: 118,
    scale: 2
});
poly.setFill({
image: imageObj,
offset: {x: 0, y: 0}
});
```

And i'm wondering if there is a way to **fade in** the opacity of the image fill once the object has loaded? At the moment it just applies to the polygon instantly, and i can't seem to figure out how to set the opacity of the fill independently from the object itself.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setFill` merely tells the polygon object what it should fill itself with when it is supposed to draw itself. This can be image or color.

To set the opacity with which the polygon is drawn, you have the `opacity` property. What you're trying to achieve can be done by combining a timeout with a function which increases the polygon's opacity and redraws it.

```
var fadeIn = function(shape) {
    var o = shape.getOpacity();
    o = o + 0.1 >=1 ? 1 : o + 0.1;
    shape.setOpacity(o);
    shape.getLayer().draw();
    if(o !== 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                fadeIn(shape);
            }, 120);
    }
};
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yhxPW/)**.

**EDIT**:

There seems to be no way to set the opacity of the fill currently in KinectJS. I've been trying to see if I can find a workaround, though.

One way to do it is, as you mentioned, drawing another polygon with only the stroke and an empty fill over the polygon with the fill, and removing the stroke polygon once the fading in has finished.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/X42VS/8/)**.

Another way would be to change the `drawFunc` for the particular polygon.

Whenever a particular layer's `draw` function is called, `drawScene` and `drawHit` functions are called for all its children. `drawScene` and `drawHit` functions for `Kinetic.Shape` call the object's `drawFunc`. `drawScene` sets the `globalAlpha` based on the shape's opacity before calling `drawFunc`.

The way `drawFunc` for `Kinetic.Polygon` is set up is that first, a path is formed on the context for the sides of the polygon. Then it is filled, followed by stroke. The way filling is done is simply setting the `fillStyle` of the context based on the fill of the polygon, and then `context.fill` is called.

How is the fill style set with images? When `setFill` is called for a polygon and the object passed as argument has the property `image`, `fillType` is considered to be `'PATTERN'`. When the path made by `drawFunc` is to be filled, a pattern is created using the image and `context.createPattern` and set as the fill style. Opacity is never considered.

But, we can make a particular polygon consider the fill's opacity by changing its `drawFunc` with `setDrawFunc`. I simply copied the `drawFunc` from KinectJS source and added a condition to fill patterns differently by considering opacity passed with `setFill`.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Udzj/2/)**.

Note that, though, this breaks the `mouseover` event for some reason. It'd be best to stick to method one until I, or someone else, for that matter, figures out what makes the `mouseover` not work when `drawFunc` is changed.

**EDIT 2**:

I managed to figure it out!

A polygon's `drawHitFunc` is the same as its `drawFunc`. So when we change the `drawFunc`, we end up changing the `drawHitFunc` which creates problems for when hit detection is required - as is the case with `mouseover` events.

So, when we change the `drawFunc` for a polygon, if we also change the `drawHitFunc` with `setDrawHitFunc` so that it is the same as the **original** `drawFunc`, we avoid breaking the hit-detection.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hZqeA/)**.

Comment: A-ha! So the only way to preserve the outline/stroke of the shape, and have the fill appear to fade-in, is to have 2 shapes overlaid on top of each other? One for the stroke, and one for the fill? Then remove the stroke only shape once the transition is complete?

Comment: Well, that could be one way to do it. You could probably ensure that the fill polygon has no stroke at all. From your question, I'd assumed you wanted to have the whole thing fade in. Let me see if there is something to set the fill opacity separately.

Comment: @Scotty I updated the answer, it is still a bit incomplete though.

Comment: Massive legend for trying to figure this out, @Rikonator! :) The second example looks very interesting! Shame the rollover breaks - that's kinda important. I'm going to keep investigating, and will report back if i figure anything out! I may have to go with example #1 due to time constraints, but i'm not sure it's the best method in terms of performance, so hopefully there is a cleaner solution!

Comment: @Scotty I figured out what was wrong and updated the answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Haha! Love it!! Cheers buddy! I reckon your fix is worth pull requesting on GitHub! Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 1):

yes there's a way to do this.  use the transitionTo method to fade the shape opacity like this:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-linear-transition-tutorial-with-kineticjs/

If you want to have a stroke applied, that stays opaque the whole time, you can simply create another shape with a stroke only that sits on top of the shape filled with an image